# If BQP contains NP, does this mean that P=NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, quantum-computing, np

There is a question raised by Scott Aaronson in one of his papers [1]: "Could we show that if NP ⊆ BQP, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses?". Assuming the answer is yes, and it is also know that if P=NP then PH collapses to the 0th level.

Based on the above two statements, I would like to ask if BQP contains NP, does this imply that P=NP?

[1] http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bqpph.pdf

Comment: Can you give a specific source for the statement on the collapse of $\mathbb{PH}$. Is it in this [2009 paper](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bqpph.pdf) by Aaronson? I could only find the result that $\mathbb{PH}$ collapses to the second level provided that $\mathbb{NP} \subseteq \mathbb{BQP} \subseteq \mathbb{AM}$. Trivially $\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{NP} \implies \mathbb{NP} \subseteq \mathbb{BQP}$. This is the opposite direction of what you're asking, which from a quick search seems to me as an open problem.

Comment: No. Even the stronger assumption $\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{BPP}$ is not known to imply lower collapse than $\mathrm{NP}=\mathrm{RP}$ (and $\mathrm{PH}=\mathrm{BPP}$). In particular, it is not known to imply $\mathrm{NP}=\mathrm{coNP}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, maybe post your answer as an answer?

Comment: @usul: OK, I’ve converted the comment to an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, no such result is known, and I never said it was!  Maybe I said it would be great to have such a result, or something like that.

Comment: This question is a bit worrying given the sequence of recent Younes "NP in BQP" preprints: http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05061.

Comment: @ScottAaronson. Many thanks for your comment. I was just assuming a positive answer for a question you asked in one of your papers:
"Fourth, a major challenge for quantum computing research is to get better evidence that quantum computers cannot solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time. As an example, could we show that if NP ⊆ BQP, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses? At ﬁrst glance, this seems like a wild hope; certainly we have no idea at present how to prove anything of the kind."

http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bqpph.pdf

Comment: @HuckBennett. Many Thanks for your comment. I didn't make that claim in the preprint.

Comment: @AhmedYounes: The second sentence of the abstract of the paper I linked to says "The paper shows that BQP contains NP." Are you saying that that's not correct?

Comment: @HuckBennett. No, I mean that I didn't mention in the paper neither P=NP nor PH will collapse if BQP contains NP.

Comment: @ScottAaronson. The question has been edited to show that it is a question not a statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, $\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{BQP}$ is not known to imply $\mathrm P=\mathrm{NP}$. Even the stronger assumption $\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{BPP}$ is not known to yield a deeper collapse than $\mathrm{NP}=\mathrm{RP}$ and $\mathrm{PH}=\mathrm{ZPP^{RP}}=\mathrm{BPP}$; in particular, it is not even known to imply $\mathrm{NP}=\mathrm{coNP}$. (However, all these implications are likely true by virtue of their premises being false.)